# Unable to get value of input field, even through text() and val() methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I want to get the value of an input field that a user will type into, then do things with it. I've tried the two ways to get value , `text()` and `val()`, on the input fields, but neither work.

Kindly advise on what it could be that I'm missing here.

*What happens exactly in the code below is that after hovering a button, the value of an input field would be shown through an alert() function. But the alert is constantly blank.*

**HTML**

```
<div id="collection_name">
collection name
</div>

<input type="text" id="collection_title" placeholder="Midnight in New York">

<div id="collection_button"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
 var collection_title = $('#collection_title').text();
 var collection_button = $('#collection_button');


 collection_button.on({

    mouseover: function() {
    alert(collection_title); // the alert comes out blank

  }
 });
```

Comment: I mis-typed my code, it's been corrected. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the `text()/val()` methods within the handler itself

```
var collection_title = $('#collection_title');
 var collection_button = $('#collection_button');


 collection_button.on({

    mouseover: function() {
    alert(collection_title.val()); //or .text() depending on the element type

  }
 });
```

The reason it was blank before is at the time of initializing

```
var collection_title = $('#collection_title').text();
```

it had no text value

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fhr2h35/). I get the idea, but it doesn't work

Comment: @JiFus, whoops, mixed the `text` with `val`. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5o3n6rdu/1/)

```
 var collection_title = $('#collection_name').text();
 var collection_button = $('#collection_button');


collection_button.on({

 mouseover: function () {

     alert(collection_title); // the alert comes out blank

 }
});
```